# Make a function's prototype a constructor itself

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

Reasonably difficult to describe, probably best through code.

```
function Base() {}
Base.prototype = function() {
    // I am a constructor
}
const baseInstance = new Base()
const secondInstance = new baseInstance() // baseInstance is not a constructor
```

I understand it would be very simple if I made the constructor a named property of `.prototype` but I would like to be able to do the pattern above in my code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've worked it out. It's a bit of a hack. Just jam an `Object.assign()` into the constructor.

```
function Base() {
    return Object.assign(
        function SecondConstructor() {},
        Base.prototype
    )
}
Base.prototype = function() {
    // This can now have properties which
    // will be attached to the constructor
}
const baseInstance = new Base()
// baseInstance is now a constructor
const secondInstance = new baseInstance()
```

Untested, but I've been using a similar concept in my code.

Enjoy!